# Deleting selected row of datagrid from database?

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and a delete button in my form. When I click the delete button, it should delete the selected row of datagrid from my Access database. but it is just removed from the datagrid not the database. when I load the form again the deleted rows are still there. Here is the code of my delete button:

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
comnd.Connection = con;
string q = "delete  from customers";
comnd.CommandText = q;
comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("delete");
```

Comment: this above code is working but it deletes all data from database, but i just want to delete only the row Im selecting from datagrid

Comment: So you'll have to pass the ID from the form to the delete method.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing some sort of ID to the database so that we can delete the specified rows? This sql query deletes the entire data

Comment: u mean the id of that row whom im selecting?

Comment: how can i get the Id from data grid and use it in sql command?

Comment: How you are adding the data to datagrid? If you use some databinding with objects, you can find the selectedItem and use the id to pass to the database

like 

string q = "delete  from customers where id = "+id;

Comment: @RanaRashid yes the dataGrid that you have displayed might be from some table, you might have some Identifier for each record like a primary key or a username. You should be passing this to the Database using where clause. LIke 
"Delete from customers where id="The id"

Answer (score 1):

So you try to delete a single row from your database, with the following query:

```
delete from customers
```

The problem is that this query does not specify which row should be affected by it. You have to understand that your DataGrid here is not the same as your DataBase.

In order to delete a specific row from the database you should also specify which row it is. For example you could tell it to delete a row with a certain id:

```
delete from customers where id = 7
```

The above query will delte all rows with the id 7. But this is only one possible approach.

For this you would actually need `id`'s in your table. The following code is from a MSDN-source. It deletes entries with a specific id which comes from the datagrid:

```
int ID = (int) datagrid.DataKeys[(int) e.Item.ItemIndex];

string sql = "DELETE FROM PetTable WHERE ID=" + ID;
ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

For further information you should [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx).

Comment: Käsebrot! when i write your code, it shows error on datakeys and items. and error is "DatagridView does not contain definition of datakeys and items"

Comment: @RanaRashid this is expected. The code is not a solution to your problem it is reference how it could be done. So you also using a DataGridView and not a datagrid. Plus you will ofc have to add ID's to your tables. Please read the article I provided.

Comment: i read that bro, but how i can generate this event of data grid. because this event is not exist
datagrid_DeleteCommand()

Comment: What do you mean by event?

Comment: Just put it into your delete Buttons scope

Comment: that was the code you were talking about.
private void datagrid_DeleteCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int ID = (int) datagrid.DataKeys[(int) e.Item.ItemIndex];

    string sql = "DELETE FROM PetTable WHERE ID=" + ID;
    ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
    ReadRecords();
}

Comment: you do not need to worry about that. You have to properly adjust your string q

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate through the selected row deleting all of them something like the below

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid1.SelectedRows)
        {
            //get key
            int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[indexWhereIdStored].Value);
            // your delete logic
        }
```

If you need to delete only one selected row assuming that the first column is the key

```
if (datagrid1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
     int selectedIndex = datagrid1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

     // gets the RowID from the first column in the grid
     int rowID = int.Parse(datagrid1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
     // you can create a parameter for the @RowID
     string sql = "DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE RowID = @RowID";

     // your code for deleting it from the database

     //  refreshing the DataGridView
}
```

Comment: That is assuming he has Id's stored in the first column right?!

Comment: if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 {
                int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;                int rowID = int.Parse(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
                comnd.Connection = con;
                string q = "delete  from customers where CustomerID=RowID";
                comnd.CommandText = q;                comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("delete") }

Comment: i get ID from data grid to a textbox then tried to use it in sql query like this. but still doens't work. 
                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                   string q = "delete  from customers where CustomerID='"+txtID.Text+"'";
   comnd.CommandText = q;

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query you missing the WHERE statement you in to indicat the ID of the costumer you want to delete

Comment: this code also not working,,,, 


                          foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
           
            int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                                    con.Open();
                OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
                comnd.Connection = con;
                string q = "delete  from customers where CustomerID=RowID";
                comnd.CommandText = q;
                comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("delete");
            }

Comment: can you make a try catch and let me see the exception please

Comment: no exception is generated. i mean button is clicking but simply does not doing anything

Comment: c# is case sensitive change RowID to rowId

Comment: now this exception is generating..
datatype mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: this is my current code of delete button . which is showing above expection..










                                                                                                        con.Open(); 
                    OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
                    comnd.Connection = con;
                    string q = "delete  from customers where CustomerID='" + txtID.Text + "'";
                    comnd.CommandText = q;
                    comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("delete");

Comment: sori about bad commenting. i dont know how to send code in comments as you guys are sending

Answer (score 0):

We did it guys. i use name instead of Id in where clause to handle data type exception. here is the working code of delete button.
                   `

```
               `con.Open();
                OleDbCommand comnd = new OleDbCommand();
                comnd.Connection = con;
                string q = "delete  from customers where CustomerName='" 
                 + txtName.Text + "'";
                comnd.CommandText = q;
                comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("delete");
```

Comment: The problem is that this will always delte all the row with the same CustomerName. This is why everybody suggested to use Id's. Because they are unique!! This might work but is not a good solution and might cause some trouble.